# breaking a loop in linkedlist in java and finding complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity

I have to find out the loop in a linked list which I have found out using turtle and hare solution as follows

```
boolean hasLoop(Node first) {

    if(first == null) // list does not exist..so no loop either.
        return false;

    Node slow, fast; // create two references.

    slow = fast = first; // make both refer to the start of the list.

    while(true) {

        slow = slow.next;          // 1 hop.

        if(fast.next != null)
            fast = fast.next.next; // 2 hops.
        else
            return false;          // next node null => no loop.

        if(slow == null || fast == null) // if either hits null..no loop.
            return false;

        if(slow == fast) // if the two ever meet...we must have a loop.
            return true;
    }
}
```

and now my problem is how can I detect the beginning of the loop and also how to calculate the complexity of the program as if I increase the size of the list. The point where pointers meet will not increase in the proportion of the size of list.

Comment: down voter could you please tell the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Cracking the Coding Interview:

Imagine, as an analogy, two people racing around a track, one running twice as fast as the other. If they start off at the same place, when will they next meet? They will next meet at the start of the next lap.

Now, let’s suppose Fast Runner had a head start of k meters on an n step lap. When will they next meet? They will meet k meters before the start of the next lap. (Why? Fast Runner would have made k + 2(n - k) steps, including its head start, and Slow Runner would have made n - k steps. Both will be k steps before the start of the loop.)

Now, going back to the problem, when Fast Runner (n2) and Slow Runner (n1) are moving around our circular linked list, n2 will have a head start on the loop when n1 enters. Specifically, it will have a head start of k, where k is the number of nodes before the loop. Since n2 has a head start of k nodes, n1 and n2 will meet k nodes before the start of the loop.

So, we now know the following:

1. Head is k nodes from LoopStart (by definition).
2. MeetingPoint for n1 and n2 is k nodes from LoopStart (as shown above).

Thus, if we move n1 back to Head and keep n2 at MeetingPoint, and move them both at the same pace, they will meet at LoopStart.

```
LinkedListNode FindBeginning(LinkedListNode head) 
{
    LinkedListNode n1 = head;
    LinkedListNode n2 = head;
    // Find meeting point
    while (n2.next != null) 
    {
        n1 = n1.next;
        n2 = n2.next.next;
        if (n1 == n2) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }

     // Error check - there is no meeting point, and therefore no loop
     if (n2.next == null) 
     {
        return null;
     }

    /* Move n1 to Head. Keep n2 at Meeting Point. Each are k steps
    /* from the Loop Start. If they move at the same pace, they must
    * meet at Loop Start. */
    n1 = head;
    while (n1 != n2) 
    {
        n1 = n1.next;
        n2 = n2.next;
    }
    // Now n2 points to the start of the loop.
    return n2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no loop, then your code will perform in `Θ(n)` because you hop at least `n` times and at most `3/2*n` times.

If there is a loop, then in graph theory terms it's a cycle of length at most `n`. The distance between `fast` and `slow` on the cycle changes by exactly `1` with each hop, so they hop at most `n` times after both have entered the loop until they meet. They both have entered the loop after at most `n-1` hops, so this gives you `2*(n-1) + 2*n ∈ O(n)` worst case complexity.

[Best case complexity for loops is `O(1)` since you can enter the loop immediately, meaning after a constant number of hops, so that's not very interesting.]